# Paypal - Payouts issue on live paypal envirnment

Tags: paypal

We are using paypal payout to send money to users from our business paypal business account.
We have tested our code on sandbox and it is worked as expected.
But with live paypal and real paypal account it is not working.

Is there any issue with payouts on live site. As per my understanding everything that works on sandbox should be working on live site.

How I can debug this issue. I have already posted to support but did anyone have similar issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you switched from sandbox to live, you need to contact PayPal customer service to get the payouts permission first.Once you get approved, it should be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to request PayPal to enable PAYOUTS for your business account. Instead of contacting them manually via chat/call/email, you need to go to the account eligibility section here: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accountStatus and you should see a button "Request" or similar in the area highlighted in red.

Paypal should email you the result but in case you don't get it, just visit the same page the next day and you will see the result like you can see mine was declined.

[image: Paypal account eligibility section]