# Paypal declined payout activation request

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, payout

We are using Paypal's Payout API to do the payments to our service providers. Everything works well in sandbox mode. Now when we were ready to go live, I applied for the account eligibility activation for Payout option (I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60201668/4226479) how you can request the same.)

My request was declined and it says ***"Your application was declined. You can reapply in 28 days. In the meantime, you can test transactions in the sandbox."***

This was a disaster for me as we were planning to launch the application soon. I had a call with support team and they said there is no way we can help you by telling why your request was declined. Just wait for 30 days and apply again and we will see if it can be approved or not. One thing they said was "Your account has high-risk payments model."

There is nothing mentioned on Paypal website about who and which business models can pass the test. What to do if the transactions just work in Sandbox mode and not in live mode. It is useless. Paypal services are becoming weird day by day. I had the [same experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59194498/braintree-production-account-request-declined) with Braintree payments.

Is anyone out there who had the same experience and found any solution?

[image: Account status]

Answer (score 0):

The Payouts API documentation [has an entire side section](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/) dedicated to explaining its prerequisites, one of which is requesting access.

Unfortunately, it is normal for some types of payment products, such as payouts and gateway services (you mentioned Braintree), to not be available to every business that would like to use them.

(Even normal PayPal accounts are not usable for some types of commerce, if you read their terms of service.)

When such approvals are needed, it is best to request live access *as early in your development cycle as possible* -- ideally when you are still in the prototype phase.  And not, of course, when you are planning to launch the application soon